# Probability of getting tail with a coin toss using 2 coins

Tags: probability

A person has 2 coins one normal and one with HEAD on both sides. Now I dont know which coin he picked but the first THREE tosses are HEADs. Now whats the probability of seeing a tail next.

I think since toss is independent event, at any point the probability is 1/4.

```
Prob to pick good coin * prob of tail + prob of bad coin * prob of tail
1/2 * 1/2 + 1/2 * 0 = 1/4
```

Can anyone confirm if this is right or if there is a different solution.

Comment: If you have already seen three heads then you have a bit of evidence about the coin. You need to plug that evidence into Bayes' theorem to get the probability for the next toss.

Comment: "Since toss is independent event, at any point the probability is $\frac14$" - this is generally true, but the fact that the person got $3$ heads out of $3$ attempts gives higher odds to the fact that the person is holding the "twisted" coin (in other words, you need to base your calculations on *conditional probability*).

Comment: If he doesn't choose a coin before each flip, you already know something that allows you to say something about $P(\text{good coin})$.

Comment: I'd also want to know how that person chose the coin. Did they choose it blindly or did they get to inspect both coins and then choose, and do they have a motivation to prefer one coin over the other? (I suppose the problem was meant to be posed so that the person chose the coin randomly and that either coin was equally likely in prior probability.)

Comment: @DavidK coin was chosen randomly.

Answer (score 2):

You had no prior information about which coin it was, so suppose they were equally likely.
Three coin tosses have come up heads.  That would always happen with the second coin, but only happen once in eight with the first coin.  So the second coin is now eight times more likely than the first coin.
Put the new probabilities of the two coins into your formula.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you should be using Bayes' theorem here.

Comment: Isn't the second coin 8/9 likely, the first coin 1/9?

Comment: This answer is correct, it just needs to mention that the probability of the person to be holding the normal coin is $\frac19$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the event "tails" be $T$, the event of choosing the good coin $G$, and three heads be $3H$ then 
$$
p(T|3H) = {1\over 2} p(G|3H) 
$$
and Bayes' theorem gives
$$
p(G|3H) = {p(3H|G) p(G)\over p(3H)} = {1/8\times1/2\over p(3H)}
$$
Now
$$
p(3H) = p(3H|G) p(G) + p(3H|{\rm not } G) p({\rm not } G)
$$
$$
= 1/8 \times 1/2 + 1\times 1/2
$$
The final answer is $1/18$.

Comment: Hi Suzu; How do you get $\frac{1}{18}$ ? $\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{16}$ what am I missing?

Comment: bobbym 9/16 is the probability to get 3 heads in a row

Comment: Hi Gudradain; I see it now,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easy solution and get an answer, use [Baye's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and the answer is 1/18.

If you want to understand it, you need to split it. Answer those questions :

1. What is the probability that he picked the first coin considering that he flipped 3 heads in a row?

To answer that first question you first need :

2. What is the probability that he will flip 3 heads in a row if you don't know what coin he picked and both coin are as likely?

He has 50% chance to pick the first good coin (face and tail) and 50% change to pick the twisted coin (2 faces)

The probability to get 3 head in a row with the good coin is 1/8 and 1/1 with the twisted coin. So, the probability to get 3 heads in a row is 1/2*1/8 + 1/2*1/1 = 9/16

Then you need

3. What is the probability to get 3 heads in a row AND pick the good coin?

1/2*1/8 = 1/16

Now... You got everything you need to answer the first question. The probability he picked the first coin considering he flipped 3 heads in a row is :

(#3) / (#2) = (1/16) / (9/16) = 1/9

So... Since he has 1/9 chance to have picked the first coin and has 1/2 chance to get tail on next turn if he picked the first coin, then he got

1/9 * 1/2 = 1/18 chance to get tail on next turn

Note : Sorry for the formating. I will figure how to use Tex ...

Comment: This answer is really misleading. "If you want the easy answer use Baye's theorem" then it goes on to basically copy out all the details from Bayes' theorem as if it's not talking about Bayes' theorem. Very poor answers here.